# How to prevent Apps Script from opening multiple projects?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have an html dialog for Sheets (container bound dialog) that is used for input and saving of customer data. I made a copy of it for use in a different office, so now I have Worksheet#1 with Script project "Scripts" and Copy of Worksheet#1 with Script project "Copy of Scripts". We've made changes to Scripts so it is no longer the same as Copy of Scripts.

Sometimes Worksheet#1 triggers scripts that are in Copy of Scripts. Not sure why. On these occasions I can open up script editor and it asks which project to open (Scripts or Copy or Scripts) and once I select the right one it behaves properly until the next time this happens.

How can I insure that it always opens the correct project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see this behavior sometimes if you have multiple projects within a script.

1. Check whether you have multiple projects in one of those sheets.

   ```
   File > Open...
   ```

   Here's a spreadsheet-contained script with two projects in it:

   [image: screenshot]
2. Open the project you want to delete.
3. Delete it.

   ```
   File > Delete Project...
   ```

   [image: Delete dialog]